# Derivative of outer product of two vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus, outer-product

Given two vectors $u(x)$ and $v(x)$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $u(x), v(x)\in\mathbb{R}^m$ what is the derivative of their outer product?
$$
\frac{d}{dx} u(x) v(x)^\top = ?
$$
Perhaps it is this?
$$
\frac{d u(x)}{dx} v(x)^\top + u(x)\left(\frac{d v(x)}{dx}\right)^\top
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

Writing $u(x)=(u_1(x),\cdots, u_m(x))$ (similar for $v(x)$),

$$\big(u(x)v(x)^T\big)_{ij}= u_i(x)v_j(x).$$

**Edit**

$$(u_iv_j)'=u'_iv_j+u_iv'_j,$$

and thus $$(uv^T)'=u'v^T+u(v')^T.$$

Comment: @Euler_Salter: I edited my answer. Should be more clear now.

Comment: @Surb Okay so using the hint I guess that the derivative of the $ij^{\text{th}}$ element would be $\frac{d u_i(x)}{dx} v_j(x) + u_i(x)\frac{d v_j(x)}{dx}$ by the product rule?

Comment: @Surb do you mind helping me a bit more? I am not sure about one would go about finding the derivative from here

Comment: @Euler_Salter: I edited my answer.

Comment: @Surb thank you! Shouldn't the result be a rank $3$ tensor though?

Comment: The function $\phi:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ should have Jacobian $J_\phi\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n} \times \mathbb{R}^n$ no?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't pay attention to the fact that $x\in \mathbb R^n$ (I thought that $x\in\mathbb R$). As written, your question doesn't make sense (I've never see $\frac{d}{dx}u(x)$ to denote the jacobian). However, you should be able to adapt this easely to your case : $$(J_{uv^T})_{i}=\partial _{x_i}u(x)v(x)^T+u(x)\partial _{x_i}v(x)^T,$$ @Euler_Salter

Comment: @Surb I apologise about the notation, perhaps I could use a different one. Essentially I would like to compute the derivative of $\phi$ as defined in my question\comment above. I suppose what I am trying to calculate is better expressed as $\nabla_x u(x) v(x)^\top$

Comment: @Surb how would you write that in concise notation? (without writing just the components)

Comment: $$...=\sum_{k=1}^n (\partial _{x_i}uv^T+u\partial _{x_i}v^T)e_k$$
$$=\sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{i,j=1}^n(\partial _{x_i}uv^T+u\partial _{x_i}v^T)e_i\otimes e_j\otimes e_k.
$$ @Euler_Salter